# Common Code Behaviour

Tags: c++, c, logging, c-preprocessor

I am developing a client-server application which include some common file for debugging.
My query is on run time will separate copy of this common code(debug file) be assigned to both the modules or they share the same code space. for example:

I want to define log tag differently for client and server. For that in the make file of both the client and server i have defined two flags CLI_LOG_TAG_ENABLE and SERVER_LOG_TAG_ENABLE. Now in debug.h

```
//debug.h


#ifdef CLI_LOG_TAG_ENABLE 
#define LOG_TAG "CLIENT"
#elif SERVER_LOG_TAG_ENABLE
#define LOG_TAG "SERVER"
#endif
```

So on rum time both the flags will be enabled due to make file changes.
Can you please tell me what will be the behavior and why?

Comment: The `#elif` doesn't match the `#ifdef`. You need `#elif defined`.

Answer (score 2):

In your code,

```
#ifdef CLI_LOG_TAG_ENABLE 
#define LOG_TAG "CLIENT"
#if SERVER_LOG_TAG_ENABLE   //did you mean ifdef ?
#define LOG_TAG "SERVER"
#endif
```

To be on safer side, you can use

```
#ifdef CLI_LOG_TAG_ENABLE 
#define LOG_TAG "CLIENT"
#else
#define LOG_TAG "SERVER"
#endif
```

Just define `CLI_LOG_TAG_ENABLE` in the client module, leave the server module alone. Hope this helps!!

Comment: Thanks sourav for very wuick reply. So there will be separate copy that will be assigned to both the modules right? otherwise it will always find CLI_LOG_TAG_ENABLE as enabled and will pring CLIENT always?

Comment: in SERVER module makefile, don't define `CLI_LOG_TAG_ENABLE`. in client module makefile, define `CLI_LOG_TAG_ENABLE`. Compile two seperate instances. Right?

Comment: Yes that is what I am doing!

Answer (score 1):

So, if you have a common file that is compiled with `LOG_TAG` either set to `"CLIENT"` or `"SERVER"`, the string will be included in the source that uses `LOG_TAG` as if your source contained `"CLIENT"` or `"SERVER"` depending on what `LOG_TAG` is set to at compile time.

Assuming that the file debug.h is included in myfile.c, which looks like this:

```
cout << LOG_TAG << " Some debug message" << endl;
```

then, when myfile.c is compiled with `LOG_TAG` set to `"SERVER"`, it will use produce the same code as if you had written:

```
cout << "SERVER" << "Some debug message" << endl;
```

if it is set to `"CLIENT"`, the code will look like this:

```
cout << "CLIENT" << "Some debug message" << endl;
```

It is worth noting that this happens BEFORE the proper compiler sees the code - the preprocessor is a separate step (and it doesn't have a clue whether you are compiling C, processing a an assembler file, or using it to produce mailmerges with `#define NAME "Mr Mats Petersson"` and something like `Dear NAME, my name is John Smith, and I'm writing to inform you that my client, a prince in my country, would like to borrow your bank account to transfer $12188138 out of the country`.)

It is also important when using this sort of trick that you compile the sources to a separate directory, or your build system may not realize that the file myfile.c needs to be recompiled with the new setting, and then your logging will be VERY confusing.